# How to determine if ElGamal message was a quadratic residue?

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Consider the following ElGamal encryption (using a generator of $\mathbb Z^*_p$):

Key gen:

- find a big prime $p$ and $g$ a generator of $\mathbb Z^*_p$.
- choose $a\in \mathbb Z_{p-1}$ randomly and calculate $A\leftarrow g^a \bmod p$
- the private key is $(p,g,a)$ and the public key is $(p,g,A)$

Encryption:

- choose $b\in \mathbb Z_{p-1}$ randomly and calculate $B\leftarrow g^b \bmod p$
- calculate $k \leftarrow A^b \bmod p$ and $C \leftarrow m\cdot k \bmod p$
- the ciphertext is $(B,C)$

How can Eve, which has the public key and can see one ciphertext $(B,C)$, determine with prob. at least $3/4$ that the message $m$ is a quadratic residue or not?

I know that with prob. $3/4$, $k$ is quadratic residue because $k=g^{a\,b}$ and $a$ or $b$ are even. I'm having trouble in determining the same thing about $m$.

Comment: Is this homework?  BTW: I have no idea where 3/4 is coming from; someone with the public key and the encryption can always determine the QR-ness of $m$.

Comment: Hint: Recall the law of quadratic residuosity:$$\forall u\in\mathbb Z_p,\ \forall v\in\mathbb Z_p,\ \left(\frac {u\,v}p\right)=\left(\frac up\right)\cdot\left(\frac vp\right)$$where $\left(\frac up\right)$ is the Legendre symbol for $u$, with $\left(\frac up\right)=u^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$, which always is $+1$ or $-1$ for $u\in\mathbb Z_p^*$.